# Car doesn't start, how can I make sure the problem is because of the battery?

Tags: battery, toyota, starting, highlander

I have a 2008 highlander. Yesterday I started the car and it was OK with no sign of weak battery. But today it didn't start. I want to know if there is any battery alarm on the dash to check if the problem is because of the battery?

Also door locks, dash lights, radio work but when I try to start the engine I can hear a weak sound like turning the window up/down while I am keeping the key in start position but nothing else happens.

I can see "charging system warning light" and "Electric Power Steering (EPS) Warning Light" are on.

I am also suspicious about pouring water in some parts around the windshield wiper water container because I tried to fulfill it carelessly and water felt in some parts around(I did this before starting the car today).

Comment: Have you checked the battery voltage? Should be at least 12.5vdc with the vehicle not running and ~13.5-14.1vdc running.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2: Unfortunately I don't have a tool to measure it.

Comment: You can get a cheap digital multimeter from the likes of Harbor Freight or any of the big box home improvement centers for under $20. Or you can take the battery to any of the major auto parts stores as they will check it for free.

Comment: Batteries can fail between one start and the next. Borrow a known good battery and test. If it works buy a new one. Some cars are well-known for needing batteries in very good condition…

Comment: Do you have jump leads?

Answer (score 1):

Take the battery to a local auto parts or battery shop and ask them to load test it.  That will tell you if the battery is good or bad.

Load testing is much more reliable than a simple voltmeter test because there are many battery failure modes that allow the battery to read normal voltage but it's still defective.

Also while you are in there, inspect the battery terminals as well as the cables and the cable attachments to the car for damage or corrosion.

Answer (score 1):

The sound you hear could be the starter motor turning, but not engaging with the flywheel.

You could try jump leads to another vehicle, or swap the battery with another vehicle’s to see if it makes a difference.

Can you record the sound you hear and post it so we can listen?  Best do this with the hood/bonnet open and put the recording device close but a safe distance from the noise.